# Why is my promise not displaying with the async pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, angular-template

I've got a promise that contains data I need to display in a HTML template, but it's not displaying.

In the method below, I can console.log `inner.data()` and find the data I need to use. All the remains is to display it in my template:

```
async getDay() {
    try {
      let ref = this.db.getDay(this.dateFirebase);
      this.day = await ref.then(out => {
        out.get().then(inner => {
          inner.data();
        });
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

My template looks like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{ day }}
    <div *ngFor="let item of day | async">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The component property `this.day` is definitely *a* promise, but I can't be sure if it's the right one. When I try to display it here, my modal very clearly appears with an `[object Promise]`. The logical next step should be to use the async pipe to display the resolved value of this promise.

This seems to be the correct notation. `day` is definitely a promise. `inner.data()` definitely contains the right data. The async pipe is used. Despite this, nothing displays. There are no template errors thrown to suggest that the template is wrong, but nothing displays as if there's just nothing *to* display.

Another suggestion told me that a HTML template has to be given an unresolved promise, and it display the promise after it has been resolved, but this doesn't sound right to me and would be really inconvenient if it was true.

Comment: How is `this.day` a promise when you are awaiting it?

Comment: Also, some strong typing would definitely help to work out what's going on here

Comment: If you recreate this in a trivial scenario, the `async` pipe will do the resolving for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9ua1n Can you recreate your scenario in a stackblitz?

Comment: I tried but I can't seem to reproduce it properly. My app is getting its `ref` value from a method I've got in `FirebaseService.ts`, which just gets a record which matches `dateFirebase`, but when I try to create pretty much the same data and send it from a service to `app-component.ts` it seems to work in Stackblitz. I'm not sure what fundamental thing I've probably screwed here. Not sure what's really different apart from my app getting its data from firebase. The data is definitely the same.

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, `inner` in this case is a `DocumentSnapshot` from Firebase that returns said document's data once `.data()` is called. Doesn't it stand to reason that since I have to call this method to get the data, the template will only be able to display the result of this method and not just `async` over the Promise? If so, how would I even go about using the result of `inner.Data()` in the template?